# php random string with one number and one letters

Tags: php

I have this function for generate random string. this worked But I need to generate one number and one letters always to random string.

```
function random() {
    $alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWXYZ0123456789!@#$%^&*()_+=-";
    $pass = array(); //remember to declare $pass as an array
    $alphaLength = strlen($alphabet) - 1; //put the length -1 in cache
    for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
        $n = rand(0, $alphaLength);
        $pass[] = $alphabet[$n];
    }
    return implode($pass); //turn the array into a string
}
```

how do edit my code and generate one number and letters in random string.

Comment: Any particular reason you need this random string? You could use PHP's `uniqid('')` function.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to produce, what is some example output?

Comment: If you're worried about making a high-quality password, just ensuring there's always a number or letter will not fix this function. rand() has no entropy worth mentioning.

Comment: @JayDansand: Yes i need to genarete a high-quality password + random String.

Comment: either limit your rand() limits to where the digits show up in your characters string, or have a separate string with just the numbers in it.

Comment: @kery: example output: `@Km-)d%=` this output not have any number!! i need to add always one number to output.

Comment: @NoneCoder If you're trying to do password hashing [this is the way to do it](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/704865/Salted-Password-Hashing-Doing-it-Right). There's even the source code to the PHP version of it [here](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#phpsourcecode).

Comment: @NoneCoder You can get better quality passwords using my second function version (updated answer). For bonus points use /dev/urandom and/or openssl_random_pseudo_bytes() if available on your platform.

Answer (score 0):

This will work, but keep in mind it's a terrible method to make a password.

```
function random() {
  $alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWXYZ0123456789!@#$%^&*()_+=-";
  $pass = array(); //remember to declare $pass as an array
  $alphaLength = strlen($alphabet) - 1; //put the length -1 in cache
  $pass[] = $alphabet[rand(0, 49)]; // Grab a random letter.
  $pass[] = $alphabet[rand(50, 59)]; // Grab a random number.
  for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
      $n = rand(0, $alphaLength);
      $pass[] = $alphabet[$n];
  }
  shuffle($pass);
  return implode($pass); //turn the array into a string
}
```

Here's a slightly better version that uses some real-ish pseudo entropy.

```
function random() {
  srand(time());
  mt_srand(rand());
  srand(mt_rand());
  // You might also want to use openssl_random_pseudo_bytes() if available and
  // not on a Windows w/PHP < 5.3 host.
  // On Linux, think about including from /dev/urandom.
  $entropy = str_split(hash('sha256', uniqid('awesomesalt', TRUE) . mcrypt_create_iv(64) . microtime() . rand() . mt_rand(), TRUE));
  $alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWXYZ0123456789!@#$%^&*()_+=-";
  $pass = array(); //remember to declare $pass as an array
  $alphaLength = strlen($alphabet); //put the length in cache
  $rand = floor(ord(array_pop($entropy)) * 50 / 255.1);
  $pass[] = $alphabet[0 + $rand]; // Grab a random letter.
  $rand = floor(ord(array_pop($entropy)) * 10 / 255.1);
  $pass[] = $alphabet[50 + $rand]; // Grab a random number.
  for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
      $rand = floor(ord(array_pop($entropy)) * $alphaLength / 255.1);
      $pass[] = $alphabet[$rand];
  }
  shuffle($pass);
  return implode($pass); //turn the array into a string
}
```